# Properly allocating short / long jumps in a VM with only absolute jumps

Tags: virtual-machine, code-generation, bytecode

Using relative jumps and assuming the code is being lowered from a structured language (so jumps are nested), the code can be generated "inside out": the inner jumps are resolved (to short or long) leading to precise offset allowing outer jumps to be resolved immediately.

If jumps are absolute though that seems like an issue: it's obviously impossible to resolve inner jumps before outer ones (as the destination offsets are not yet known), but resolving outer jumps require assuming a size for the inner jumps, and any mis-prediction requires updating the outer jump which can cascade into updating the inner jumps, which then requires re-updating the outer jumps, ....

Is there a better solution than this iteration until the jumps converge?

This assumes long jumps have a longer encoding and are more expensive than short jumps, so are undesirable (or possibly forbidden entirely e.g. the ISA forbids "overlong" encodings).

Comment: How does “size for the inner jumps” matter with absolute addresses? The size of the absolute address depends on the base address, so you’ll use a size matching the address space and that’s it. There’s a reason why all attempts to reduce the instruction size boil down to switching to relative addressing—at least for the short jump instruction.

Comment: @Holger if I have a jump from A to A'target and there's an other jump B between A and A'target, the space allocated for B will influence the location of A'target.

Comment: "There’s a reason why all attempts to reduce the instruction size boil down to switching to relative addressing" as noted theres is no relative addressing here, it's not a thing in the VM, there's short absolute and long absolute. That's the entire problem.

Comment: Your entire problem is artificial. You wrote “this assumes long jumps have a longer encoding and are more expensive than short jumps” but are talking about *absolute addresses* all the time. But absolute addresses are just that, absolute. They do not depend on whether the jump is short or long. They just depend on the address value itself. Again, if you want to have less expensive short jump instructions, you need relative addressing. If you don’t have such instructions, you don’t need do ask questions about such instructions.

Comment: @Holger the problem is absolutely not artificial, it's the cpython VM, all jumps are in the context of a stack frame, most jumps are absolute (especially the conditional ones), there is one byte of "free" payload per instruction and an additional instruction (`EXTENDED_ARG`) is necessary for each additional byte. So this is in fact a situation with variable-width absolute jumps.

Comment: And to note that the exact same issue could occur on real hardware, there's nothing precluding the head of the address space being privileged in the ISA (especially if the ISA uses some sort of banking / segmentation)

Comment: No hardware designer would create this problem, as they know that there’s the simple solution to just use relative addressing. The scenario you describe with Python still doesn’t contradict what I wrote. How many bytes the absolute address needs, depends on the address, not whether it is a short or large branch. When your instruction’s address is already 0x100, a forward branch can’t use a single byte, no matter how short it is. The same applies for instructions after 0x10000, etc. Crossing such a border is rare compared to the overall code size. The larger the code, the less it will happen.

Comment: "How many bytes the absolute address needs, depends on the address, not whether it is a short or large branch." Congratulation you unhelpfully managed to correctly nitpick on a mostly irrelevant point of linguistic imprecision I guess? What would be the correct term for jumps for differentiating between "cheap" jumps to the start of the address space and "expensive" jumps to further into it then?

Comment: "Crossing such a border is rare compared to the overall code size. The larger the code, the less it will happen." which helps none at all when most of the addresses are small because most of the code is relatively short and the addresses are all relative to the stackframe, so many functions have a significant amount of code around that boundary.

Comment: That’s not nitpicking. Since you know beforehand, how many bytes the start address of a basic block needs, you only need to regenerate the code when the block has crossed the border. Which means 1) for the first border, at most 256 bytes need to be regenerated. For the remaining code, you know that you need at least two bytes, even for small jumps. 2) reaching the second border may never happen at all in practice. Even if you happen to cross it, the basic block that needs to be regenerated is likely very small compared to the large amount of code for which the optimistic assumption worked.